# Advanced MySQL pattern matching (beyond LIKE...%)

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, sql-like

This is the example of my current MySQL my_table...

```
 id          name       code
 1           111        XXXX123456XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 2           222        XXXX133456XXXXXXX5XXXXXX
 3           333        XXXX123454XXX11XXXXXXABC
```

Code is a 24 character hexadecimal value where X is the wildcard.

I need to write a query that will return the NAME based on the CODE without a wildcard value X. 
The given CODE value will be exact but it should compare the string in place, X could match any character.

For example:

SELECT name FROM my_table where code = '012312345611111111111111';

```
 name
 111
```

SELECT name FROM my_table where code = '000013345622222225123456';

```
 name
 222
```

SELECT name FROM my_table where code = '000123454ABC11234567FABC';

```
 name
 333
```

Comment: You could use regular expressions: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html

Comment: I don't follow the logic of your suggested matches.  What are you trying to match in the table and then what pattern do you want to use for that match?

Comment: Given code in the WHERE clause 012312345611111111111111 would match a wildcard value in the table XXXX123456XXXXXXXXXXXXXX. The values match because there is '123456' is in the 4 through9th position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `like` for this.  Are you aware of the `_` wildcard?

```
select t.*
from t
where @YourCode like replace(t.code, 'X', '_');
```

Of course, you can use regular expressions too. The regular expression would be:  `concat('^', replace(t.code, 'X', '.'), '$')`.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks! How expensive using _ wildcard replace function as opposed to the regular expression. I have tens of thousands of codes in the my_table

Comment: I think `like` is generally faster than regular expressions, but feel free to test and see which works better.